# Extracting data from a wikipedia page

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, wikipedia

This question might be really specific. I am trying to extract the number of employees from the Wikipedia pages of companies such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3M.

I tried using the Wikipedia python API and some regex queries. However, I couldn't find anything solid that I could generalize for any company (not considering exceptions).

Also, because the table row does not have an id or a class I cannot directly access the value. Following is the source:

```
<tr>
<th scope="row" style="padding-right:0.5em;">
<div style="padding:0.1em 0;line-height:1.2em;">Number of employees</div>
</th>
<td style="line-height:1.35em;">89,800 (2015)<sup id="cite_ref-FY_1-5" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-FY-1">[1]</a></sup></td>
</tr>
```

So, even though I have the id of the table - `infobox vcard` so I couldn't figure out a way to scrape this information using `beautifulSoup`.

Is there a way to extract this information? It is present in the summary table on the right at the beginning of the page.

Comment: You should post your own attempts at fixing the issue. If it's always the same table with the row name, couldn’t you extract that from the html?

Comment: Updated the post. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe not the best way, but still: go through all <tr>s and look for 'Number of employees' in innerHTMLof each <tr> . Then parse the innerHTML to get the data you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `lxml.etree` instead of BeautifulSoup, you can get what you want with an XPath expression:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3M')
>>> doc = etree.fromstring(r.text)
>>> e = doc.xpath('//table[@class="infobox vcard"]/tr[th/div/text()="Number of employees"]/td')
>>> e[0].text
'89,800 (2015)'
```

Let's take a closer look at that expression:

```
//table[@class="infobox vcard"]/tr[th/div/text()="Number of employees"]/td
```

That says:

> Find all `table` elements that have attribute `class` set to `infobox
>   vcard`, and inside those elements look for `tr` elements that have a
>   child `th` element that has a child `div` element that contains the
>   text "Number of employees", and inside that `tr` element, get the
>   first `td` element.

Comment: The explanation and solution both are really clear. Thanks so much!

Comment: XPath is fun if you think of it as an Infocom style text-adventure game.

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel?

### DBpedia

has this information in RDF triples.

See e.g.
http://dbpedia.org/page/3M